# Philip Glass Etude 16 fingering

Tags: piano, fingering

Fellow pianists, what’s your way of playing motifs from the 16th etude by Philip Glass?

I mean the

- d-e flat-d-c sharp-double d; and
- d-e flat-d-c-double b flat?

M1

[image: Measures on either side of rehearsal mark 4]

M2

Sorry it is typeset across the line only.

[image: measure before rehearsal mark 5] [image: measure after rehearsal mark 5]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Excerpt 1

##### Option A

For the first excerpt — `D-Eb-D-C# D:D` — the critical element is using finger `2` on the `C#`. It's not an easy movement to the following octave, particularly getting finger `5` in place on time, but that's the way to do it. The first three notes are a matter of comfort. `3-4-3` or `1-3-1` are both good options.

##### Option B

A second possibility, if absolutely necessary, would be to use the thumb on `C#` and then "slide" over the following `D`. In that case, the fingering would be `2-3-2-1 1:5`.

#### Excerpt 2

Here again, finger `2` on `C` is the key element. The movement to be `Bb` octave is tricky because of the need for the short thumb to travel all the way to the `Bb`. In this case, `1-3-1-2 1:5` is probably best, because it allows the thumb to be close to the `Bb` right from the beginning. Just make sure when playing the `D`, the thumb is close to the front edge of the `Eb`.

Comment: I think I find Option B fractionally easier than Option A for excerpt 1, but they're both okay for me at the marked tempo.

For excerpt 2 I'd go 3-4-3-2 1:5 though, I think.